# I am trying to create a authentication using passport js, but I am getting an error while passing a parameter (passport) in the router.get

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, passport.js

This code works fine in just one file, I wanted to separate the code into a route, controller files. When passing this OAuth passport authentication, I am getting an error.

```
//route.js code
router.get("/auth/google", [passport.authenticate("google", { scope: ["profile"] })], auth.googleGet);

//Error I am getting
Error: Route.get() requires a callback function but got a [object Undefined]
```

Answer (score 0):

router.get needs a callback function as it's second param. You are passing an Array in to it. That's why you are getting the error.